# Error to return php value with ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a question,I'd like to send data using method post using ajax call,so I do like that:

```
       jQuery.noConflict();

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax?uid="+<?php echo   $sf_user->getGuardUser()->getId() ?>+"fid="+<?php echo $user->getId() ?>+"fn="+<?php echo $user->getfirstName() ?> +"ln="+<?php echo $user->getlastName() ?>, // 
                data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#thanks").html(msg)
                    $("#form-content").modal('hide');   
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Something is wrong!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But It seems not working for me, i get this strange error :

```
ReferenceError: Jean is not defined url: "ajax?uid="+1+"fid="+13+"fn="+Jean +"ln="+paul, //
```

Very strange because when I remove `fn and ln` and I keep just the number value it works very well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the string values within `''`.. Values like Jean is a string value, so it need to be enclosed within `''` else it will be considered as a variable and during execution time when it is looked up, the js engine will not find it causing the said error.

```
url: "ajax?uid="+<?php echo   $sf_user->getGuardUser()->getId() ?>+"fid="+'<?php echo $user->getId() ?>'+"fn="+'<?php echo $user->getfirstName() ?>' +"ln="+'<?php echo $user->getlastName() ?>', //
```

Comment: @downvoter did I miss anything here

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.ready()` is an event which fires when page is loaded.

Thus only code that accesses the DOM should be in ready handler. If it's a plugin, it shouldn't be in the ready event.

Thus don't put your ajax call within ready function.